# QNetworkAccessManager request fail (CA signed certificate)

Tags: qt, ssl

I've got a CA signed certificate which I use for a webservices. In Chrome and Firefox everything work fine.

Now I want to write a QT-client for the webservice. But all what I get is "connection closed" after 30 seconds. If I request "https://gmail.com" or "https://www.dfn.de/" I get a proper result.

Here is my code.

```
void Request::send() {
    QUrl url("my url");
    qDebug() << "URL: " << url;

    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::UserAgentHeader, userAgent);

    QObject::connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::authenticationRequired, this, &Request::provideAuthenication);
    QObject::connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this , &Request::replyFinished);
    QObject::connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::sslErrors, this , &Request::sslErrors);

    qDebug() << "fire request";
    manager->get(request);
}

void Request::provideAuthenication(QNetworkReply *, QAuthenticator *ator) {
    qDebug() << "provideAuthenication";
    ator->setUser("***");
    ator->setPassword("***");
}

void Request::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply) {
    if (reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError)
        qDebug() << "Network Error: " << reply->errorString();

    QVariant statusCode = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute );
    QVariant statusPhrase = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpReasonPhraseAttribute );
    qDebug() << "Result: " << statusCode.toInt() << " " << statusPhrase.toString();
    qDebug() << "Data: " << reply->readAll();
}

void Request::sslErrors(QNetworkReply *, const QList<QSslError> &errors) {
    foreach (const QSslError &error, errors) {
        qDebug() << "SSL Error: " << error.errorString();
    }
}
```

And that is the output. No sslError! No HTTP Error!

```
URL: QUrl( "my url" )
Network Error: "Connection closed"
Result: 0
Data: ""
```

So why hangs QT or the server? Did I miss something?!

Comment: *"connection closed after 30 seconds"* - that sounds like it could be a DNS error. What does `dig <domain> a` return? Can it resolve the domain? *"Connection closed"* on its own sounds like the connection is being REJECTed by a firewall. But it should happen immediately, and not after 30 seconds. A 30 second delay could be a firewall DROP, but you should not get a "connection closed" since the packet is silently discarded.

Answer (score 0):

It was a misconfiguration of openjdk7 (glassfish).

The hint of Aldaviva works on *serverfault* for me. https://serverfault.com/questions/389197/ssl-routinesssl23-writessl-handshake-failure

To bad that QT do not throw an ssl-error.